# jquery not working with if statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, forms

I am using an jquery script with an ajax update method that is bound to the focus event of a form element. It works, but I first want to check if the form element is not empty. As soon as I do that, the function stops working. Below is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ($('#txt_updateone').val().trim().length > 0) {
        function single_change(txt_updateone) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { "txt_updateone": 1 },
                url: "single_scorechange.php",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#listinscore').load(document.URL + '#listinscore');

                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });

            return false;

        }
    }
</script>
```

txt_updateone is a textarea and the onfocus event calls the single_change function. When I remove the if..... on the second line, it works, but I want it to work only if the textarea is NOT empty.

Comment: Move the `if` statement inside the function?

Comment: does your script after your element #txt_updateone ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods.

1) Validate the data at the place where you are calling this function.

2) Validate the data before sending ajax request using `beforeSend`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function single_change(txt_updateone) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { "txt_updateone": 1 },
            url: "single_scorechange.php",
            success: function (data) {
                 $('#listinscore').load(document.URL + '#listinscore');
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                alert("Enter some value");
                return $('#txt_updateone').val().trim().length > 0 ? true: false;
            }
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this one is the best one.+1

Comment: Thanks a million Nagarjiun! It works perfectly! Thank you again and again and again!

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned `if` condition before the function, the function is actually declared there. So you are calling the undefined function.

```
function single_change(txt_updateone) {
    if ($('#txt_updateone').val().trim().length < 1) {
        //form element is empty
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { "txt_updateone": 1 },
        url: "single_scorechange.php",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#listinscore').load(document.URL + '#listinscore');

        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert("error");
        }

    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is always the best to have only one exit from function, now you have 2, but will also work.

Comment: it's called `early return` rather than wrapping entire ajax call into the if loop. this makes better readability.

Comment: @tilz0R is coding style, you do not need to downvote for that. compare your and my answer check which one is much readable?

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam  you are doing oposit what OP needs. he needs that if length is gretaer than 0 then only ajax will run.You are doing opposite of that

Comment: Thanks, @AlivetoDie for pointing out the issue. I did not see that.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
function single_change(txt_updateone) {
  if ($('#txt_updateone').val().trim().length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          "txt_updateone": 1
        },
        url: "single_scorechange.php",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#listinscore').load(document.URL + ' #
              listinscore ');

            },
            error: function(xhr) {
              alert("error");
            }

        });

      return false;

    }
  }
```

You need to perform the `if` check inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Just swap function and if statement

```
//Declare function in all cases
function single_change(txt_updateone) {
    //When you call function, check if statement.
    if ($('#txt_updateone').val().trim().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { "txt_updateone": 1 },
            url: "single_scorechange.php",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#listinscore').load(document.URL + '#listinscore');

            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is *defining* your function only if the text area is non-empty (and it is likely that when this code runs, it may be empty). I think what you mean to do is to always have the function defined, but only execute the body if the text area has content.

If that's what you want, this may work:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function single_change ( txt_updateone ) {
    var content = $('#txt_updateone').val().trim();
    if (!content.length) { return; }
    // now execute function with non-empty content.
  }

</script>
```